# Jfrog artifactory password reset

Tags: artifactory

[Screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnKJk.png) [ScreenShot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEHIL.png) I'm unable to login to jfrog artifactory with default credentials and unable to change password too.  How to reset password in Jfrog? any idea.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the admin user then you can follow these instructions:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Users+and+Groups#UsersandGroups-RecreatingtheDefaultAdminUserrecreate

If you are not an admin, you can ask your administrator to reset your password.